# Should I calculate in meters or pixels

Tags: unity, simulations, car

In my car sim I am doing my calculations in Standard Units, except for the distance which is in pixels. Is this still correct (my guess is no) or should I use Meters ?

If I should use meters what is the best way to go about it? 
should I just pick a scale 10px = 1m or is there a better way to do this ?

thanks in advance.

Some additional info: I'm using Unity3D and using its physics engine.

Comment: When you say that 1 meter = 1 pixel, it does not really matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A lot of physics engines operate at a scale of 1 unit = 1 meter.
Unity isn't any different, as you can see in the [manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Physics.html).

> The size of the your GameObject's mesh is much more important than the mass of the Rigidbody. If you find that your Rigidbody is not behaving exactly how you expect - it moves slowly, floats, or doesn't collide correctly - consider adjusting the scale of your mesh asset. Unity's default unit scale is 1 unit = 1 meter, so the scale of your imported mesh is maintained, and applied to physics calculations. For example, a crumbling skyscraper is going to fall apart very differently than a tower made of toy blocks, so objects of different sizes should be modeled to accurate scale.

So 1 unit = 1 meter. Don't use pixels for your physic engine. Your world should be  decoupled from the actual rendering output (which is in pixels)

Answer (score 2):

For the best simulation accuracy, you should choose units such that typical numbers are **close to 1 in scale**; this will ensure your physics' floating-point computations are as accurate as possible. This applies to all numbers — lengths, masses, etc.

So, for games with human-scale objects like cars, 1 = 1 meter is a perfectly fine choice. On the other hand, if you were, for example, simulating a pinball machine, it would be good to scale things so that the ball's radius is 1.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate advice. It's more important to have correct unit sizes (eg. corresponding to the meter scale) in order to have a realistic simulation. Having a pinball at the size of `0.02` units isn't going to make your simulation less accurate. Problems arise when you have objects with really large differences in size though. Eg. a pinball of size `0.02` colliding with objects of size `200000.0`.